# Is RuneScape realworld trade legal?

Tags: runescape, oldschool-runescape

I just created my first account in RuneScape!

I am not a "grinding" person and would like to kick-start my fun by purchasing some gold.

Since I am looking for old-school RuneScape, I have found a website that says they sell gold and other in-game goods, and also they claim that their services are 10% safe. So my question what is likely hood to get any penalty for purchasing and in general is it actually illegal to buy in-game goods with real money.

And if it's illegal, why so? What's the reason behind that.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Did you read the rules?

Comment: If company A offers the ability to do something unethical, say, by acting against the specific terms and conditions of company B, I would not consider them trustworthy when they say 'company B won't find out, we promise'. It's always important to remember that *people on the Internet can lie to you*.

Comment: Yeah the company you do something against TOS being ITS BAN FREE! Would be like a guy trying to sell you pot and saying 'Don't worry! Cops can't get you because you are dealing with me!' So yeah I would not take their word for it except is Jagex would be to come out and say 'Yes this is a valid gold exchange marketplace'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking if something is illegal are off topic here.

Answer (score 5):

By *legal*, there could be two interpretations. The first one, is if it's legal in the legal sense - meaning, does it violate the sovereign law. The second, if it's against Jagex's terms of service.

For the first part, it may be best to question Law.SE, but generally speaking, the law where the customer is based tends to dictate the legality of the transaction. Depending on where you live, your mileage may vary.

For the second part, according to [Jagex's Terms and Conditions](https://www.jagex.com/en-GB/terms):

> 6. YOUR ACCOUNT AND LICENSE
>
> [...] You may not otherwise [...]Further you may not [...] or participate in any way whatsoever in any real-world trading

Which means it's not allowed by Jagex, and may have repercussions (such as account termination).

Answer (score 1):

You will not be breaking any real world law (so it is not illegal as is), but you will be breaking Runescape's Terms of Service.

You are better off paying maybe a little bit more, but use the in-game, Runescape official Cash to Gold service. Then you will not be breaking TOS and you will be sure that you will not be scammed.

It just is against the Terms that Runescape puts on every user to play the game. I do not know the exact reason why, but it just is. Probably to prevent people being scammed and then the blame being thrown back on them. Pretty much every MMO has a clause in their terms of service that makes it a bannable offense to use such services.

My guess would be that some of those gold services yes do farm the gold, but others will just hack accounts and empty them of all their gold and thats the gold you are buying. So by buying gold, you encourage that thing that is a thorn in their side, and that destroys some of their players.

Another guess would be that there is also some legal complications that could arise for Regex is there is any casino/betting minigame in game, because then you straight have a conversion from cash to virtual 'chips' and then you run afoul of the gambling laws in lots of countries, because that stuff varies A LOT from country to country.

Comment: What is the reason it's against tos? I am new to games where you can purchase currencies or accounts. I am more offline gamer.

Comment: I’m not a lawyer or anything, but if I’m not mistaken, most game companies put this type of clause in their TOS to prevent people (along with the right to permanently ban players) from profiting on digital property that is owned by the developer, not the seller

Comment: Note that man-in-the-middle sellers, such as the website OP referenced are actually illegal by law and can be sued for 1) making money on the intellectual property of the publisher and 2) preventing players from spending money on services provided by the publisher.

Comment: In-game currencies that are distributed in any fashion by the game/developers themselves, are *not* the same as paying some random person on the internet for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Third-party 'real world trading' (RWT) sites are not allowed under RuneScape terms of service, neither for Oldschool RuneScape nor for RuneScape 3. If you are caught buying gold, your account will be banned and you will lose the purchased goods as well as any progress you made yourself.

Not every gold purchase will be detected, but the way that large-scale gold farming works is that usually either accounts are hacked, or else bots are used. Sometimes gold is purchased from other accounts (many gold selling websites also buy gold from players) but this is less common. RuneScape deletes bots in waves to avoid letting bot developers know how their bots were detected, and when these ban waves come through, the gold they traded away is tracked and often whichever account ended up with it is also banned. Likewise, when someone reports that their account has been hacked, it's possible to trace where the gold from it ended up. Generally if you wind up with botted or stolen gold, RuneScape will assume you either bought it (which is not allowed) or you were involved in the hacking/botting (which is also not allowed).

It's possible to purchase in-game gold with real-world money by buying [Bonds](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Old_school_bond) and selling them on the Grand Exchange. This is not as cheap as buying from third-party websites, but even one or two bonds will give you a very significant sum of starting cash. If you only want to give yourself a boost at the start of the game, this is probably the best path to take, as you won't risk losing your account after a few months of progress and you shouldn't need to buy much gold anyway.